# Who was Rishi Atharvan who wrote Atharva Veda?

Tags: rishi

I recently came to know about this Rishi Atharvan who is believed to have compiled the Atharva Veda along with Angiras. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atharvan) says he was a Manasputra of Brahma abut when you check the list of [Manasputras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manasputra) his name doesnt figure in it. Wiki mentions that he was the father of Dadhichi and belonged to Bhrigu clan but then Bhrigu himself is a Manasputra.

So I want to know who was he really?

Comment: There sees to be some confusion about his origins.. some scholars equate him with Angiras while others with Bhrigu.

Comment: Yes Sir would be grateful if someone could clear the confusion.